# Binary representation of a long long

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, iostream

So I've been doing some work with bitwise strings and in my travels I have need of displaying this long long in its binary form. The variable has the right value, as shown in the first cout. However, when it's displayed in binary a "1" is missing. Any ideas what's causing this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    long long truncator=4294967551ll;
    cout<<truncator<<"\n";
    std::bitset<64> b(truncator);
    cout<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

output is:
4294967551
00000000000000000000000011111111

Comment: Can you provide the output you are seeing in your question?

Comment: `string s = b.to_string(); cout << s.length();` says 64 for me.

Comment: output added per request

Comment: jrok, it's the right length, but not the right binary value

Comment: looks correct http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2ef246281f9e56d5b08edb48dee61c51-3b440a87a52fe2ae7c853c82f4c5144f

Comment: yes, A.H., that is the correct output, what could be giving me a different output? I'm using MinGW in CodeBlocks.

Comment: Also works on Visual Studio Ultimate 2012... What compiler are you using? Maybe try using `b.to_string()`?

Comment: tried b.to_string(), same output as before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/, the `std::bitset` constructor you're trying to use only uses an `unsigned long`, which, on your system, is probably just 32 bits. Other systems will have `unsigned long` be 64-bits, so others may not see this issue (try printing out `sizeof(unsigned long)`).

Only real fixes for this are to construct the bitset from the low 32 bits of `truncator`, and manually set the rest of the bits.

Comment: in windows a long is 32-bit long in unix like systems long is pointer size both have long long as 64-bit

Comment: as for the constructor  according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset it is an unsigned long long or a string

Comment: That maybe be something that was fixed in C++0x - besides, the behavior that I'm seeing hints that the constructor he's ultimately calling is only taking in 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own function to convert `long long` to a string:

```
string convertToBitString(long long value)
{
    string str(64, '0');

    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        if( (1ll << i) & value)
            str[63-i] = '1';
    }

    return str;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

How bitset handles 64-bit parameter varies between compiler. Some Visual Studio versions accept long long, other compilers only accept 32-bit long even if they have 64-bit long long available. It shouldn't be difficult to print out a binary representation though. Simple, off the top of my head, untested..

```
string str;
do
{
    str += ((truncator&1)?'1':'0');
} while (--truncator);
reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
```